# animating UIButton on the flow

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton in my application with an image.

- I want to be able to call a function that flashes that button a number of times ( say 5 times)
- I also want to be able to stop this flashing while it is running

Below is the important part of the code:

```
var flashesRemaining: Int = 5;
var isFlashing: Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var btnMM: UIButton!

// Flash the button
@IBAction func flashMemoryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(self.flashesRemaining)
    if self.flashesRemaining == 0 {
        return
    }
    if !isFlashing {
        self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.btnMM.alpha = 0.0100000003
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in })

        isFlashing = true
    }
    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in })
    }
    self.flashesRemaining = self.flashesRemaining - 1
}
```

So I want to be able to call the above function like this, to start the flashing:

```
self.flashesRemaining = 5
self.flashMemoryButton(sender: self.btnMM)
```

and then if I want to disable the blinking I should just call:

```
self.flashesRemaining = 0
```

However the above code is not working at all. Once I call

```
self.flashMemoryButton(sender: self.btnMM)
```

I get the printout **5** and then the button keeps blinking for ever.
What am I missing here?

By the way the magical number 0.0100...3 is the minimum allowed alpha for a UIButton while maintaining user interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```
func flashMemoryButton() {
    print(self.flashesRemaining)
    if self.flashesRemaining == 0 {
        btnMM.alpha = 1
        return
    }
    if !isFlashing {
        self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.btnMM.alpha = 0.0100000003
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            if finished {
                self.flashMemoryButton()
                self.flashesRemaining = self.flashesRemaining - 1
            }
        })

        isFlashing = true
    }
    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            if finished {
                self.flashMemoryButton()

            }
        })
        isFlashing = false
    }
}
```

Here's the changes I've made:

First, I removed `.repeat` and `.autoreverse`. This is because instead of the animation repeating itself, we want the `flashMemoryButton` method to be called multiple times.

Next, I added `isFlashing = false` in the `else` branch. This is so that when `isFlashing` is true, the button fades in the next time the method is called, and when `isFlashing` is false, the button fades out. You can think of `isFlashing` like a toggle.

When the fade in/out animations finish, I called `flashMemoryButton()` because when the animation finishes, you want to do another animation, right?

In the completion handler of the fade out animation, I decremented `flashesRemaining`. This is where you want to decrement it, not outside the if statement. If you put it outside, it will flash half the times you told it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount`; therefore you dont need `flashesRemaining` any more. You should also re-set the `isFlashing`-flag in the completion handler. Here my modified code:

```
var isFlashing: Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var btnMM: UIButton!

@IBAction func flashMemoryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !isFlashing {
        self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
            UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(5)
            self.btnMM.alpha = 0.0100000003
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {() -> Void in
                self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in self.isFlashing = false})
        })

        isFlashing = true
    }
    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut, .beginFromCurrentState], animations: {() -> Void in
            self.btnMM.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in self.isFlashing = false})
    }
}
```